# Jquery toggleClass not working as i expected

Tags: jquery, css

The following toggleClass does not work:

```
    $('.t').click(function() {
        var className = $(this).data('class');
        $(this).toggleClass(className).toggleClass(className+'1');
    });
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="t a" data-class="a"> 8cghfghfghfghfg</div>
 <div class="t b" data-class="b">20cghfghfghfghfg</div>
 <div class="t c" data-class="c"> 4cghfghfghfghfg</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_k28/m9ak9/)

Here, what i want to do is..
if i click on div.t, i want to remove the particular class(Ex: .a) 
and add respective class (Ex .a1)

**EDIT**
if i click on any div only that particular div should be change and the rest of the div's should be in default state
please can anyone help,
Thanks.

Comment: your demo seems to be working fine.. or did i get you wrong..?

Comment: your demo is what you said .it works fine

Comment: say if i clicked on div(.t a) then i want to remove a class (.a) and add class(.a1), the second time when i was clicking on the div(.t b), then the first div should be in default state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you also want to be able to "un-toggle" the active element, you can use this:

http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_k28/m9ak9/

```
    $('.t').click(function() {
        var currentElement = this;
        var className = $(currentElement).data('class');
        $('.t').each(function(index, element) {
            var jQelement = $(element);
            var className = jQelement.data('class');
            if (element !== currentElement) {
                jQelement.removeClass(className+1).addClass(className);
            }
        });
        $(this).toggleClass(className).toggleClass(className+'1');
    });
```

Note what happens if you click the same element twice. The element will go back to the default state.

Comment: here i'm having one more question, can i ask you??

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You can't just send me code that does one thing, and expect me to understand in what way you want it to work differently...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/hushme/m9ak9/1/

```
    $('.t').click(function() {
        var className = $(this).attr('data-class');
  $(this).toggleClass(className).toggleClass(className+'1');
    });
```

You are not getting the attr value.

Comment: .data('class') is the "correct" way to access data-attributes in jQuery. There is no need to do .attr('data-class').
And, again, the original code actually works fine.

Comment: if i click on any div only that particular div should be change and the rest of the div's should be in default state

Comment: that you have to remove other classes first

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).toggleClass(className + ' ' + className+'1');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3mk7E/)

Or if you do not want want to keep toggling

```
$(this).removeClass(className).addClass(className+'1');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3mk7E/2/)

Comment: first time when i was clicking on first div it is working fine, when i was clicking on second div, then the rest of the div's should be in default state

Answer (score 0):

here's a quick fixup to handle your reset to default state: http://jsfiddle.net/mbMhN/

```
$('.t').click(function () {

    $('.t').each(function () {
        var cls = $(this).data('class');
        $(this).removeClass(cls + "1").addClass(cls);
    });


    var className = $(this).data('class');
    $(this).toggleClass(className).toggleClass(className + '1');
});
```

Comment: If you want the currently "active" element to go to the default state when you click it again, this code does not work. This code works like radio-buttons, where you cannot deselect the selected option.

Comment: @AdrianSchmidt true. from OPs comments above, that seemed like the desired behavior